# Unable to receive wear os location in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, location, android-wear-2.0, wearables

For a project i need to receive the location of a wear os in jetpack compose. According to the settings I have location allowed, which is the highest for the location permission. However, I always get null for the last and new position. The following is my code I use to receive the location:

[image]

I already tried if i have the necessary permissions and if the watch has gps and if gps is turned on.